# Are all valid templates instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates

When I have multiple templates that could be instantiated, what happens?

```
template <typename T> void foo(T*);
template <typename T> void foo(T**);

template void foo(int**);

template <typename T> void foo(T*) { printf("called foo(T*)\n"); }
template <typename T> void foo(T**){ printf("called foo(T**)\n"); }
```

When we need to instantiate a foo(int**), either of the instantiations would work, one with T=int* and the other with T=int**. In practice, the object file only contains one, the T** one. On the other hand, if I put a `static_assert(false)` into the unused one, the compilation fails. Does that mean that it *is* instantiated?

It turns out that the T** is the one that I want to use in this case. But even if both were instantiated, overload resolution would pick the T** one, so this works for me either way.

Now in my actual code, I request two instantiations:

```
template void foo(int*);
template void foo(int**);
```

That instantiates `foo<int>(int**)` and `foo<int>(int*)`, so I get both templates. The latter is forced, since `template <typename T> foo(T**)` doesn't match. But I don't understand the rules to know why I don't get `foo<int*>(int**)` for the former. Or both `foo<int*>(int**)` as well as `foo<int>(int**)`.

And yes, I realize I could do `template void foo<int*>(int**)` if I needed to force it.

All this makes me realize I don't really understand what happens when the compiler sees a call that requires a template instantiation. Does it scan through templates until it finds one that works, then stop? Or does it instantiate all valid options (and then something discards the unneeded ones from the object file)?

Comment: I can't answer the questions you're asking, but I can answer a very important question you're *not* explicitly asking:  The compiler will do its best to resolve `T` to a pointerless type.  (It prefers `foo<int>` over `foo<int*>`).  Also, it doesn't need to instantiate anything to determine whether it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I put a `static_assert(false)` into the unused one, the compilation fails. Does that mean that it is instantiated?

No.  The compiler does some basic checks on a template definition.  Everything in the definition must be valid C++, but certain things which depend on a template parameter cannot be checked until an actual instantiation, when the template arguments are known.  Since `static_assert(false);` does not depend on any template parameters, it always causes an error, and a compiler is allowed to note the error even when the template is never instantiated.

If you really want a template that should never be instantiated, the usual way is to use `=delete` for a function template, or leave a class template undefined.

> But I don't understand the rules to know why I don't get `foo<int*>(int**)` for the former.

In most contexts that name a specialization of a function template, there's a rule that any template which is "more specialized" than all other viable overloads is the one that gets used.  The exact definition of "more specialized" is a bit tricky, but the basic idea is that if any argument list that could be taken by a function template "A" could also be taken by a function template "B" but not vice versa, then "A" is more specialized.  In your example

```
template <typename T> void foo(T*);  // #1
template <typename T> void foo(T**); // #2
```

if an argument `arg` has type `U**` for any type `U` so that template argument deduction for template #2 for `foo(arg)` can succeed with `T=U`, we can see that template argument deduction for template #1 for `foo(arg)` can also succeed with `T=U*`.  On the other hand, it's obviously possible that another argument `arg2` can mean that template argument for `foo(arg2)` can succeed for template #1 but fail for template #2, for example if `arg2` has type `int*`.  So function template #2 is more specialized than function template #1.  This means an expression like `foo(arg)`, whenever type deduction for both succeeds (and there are no other viable overloads involved), means a use of template #2.

The same "more specialized" rule applies in your explicit instantiation

```
template void foo(int**);
```

Much like with a function call expression, the compiler will use template argument deduction to see whether the declaration you gave matches each function template.  In this case both succeed, but since template #2 is more specialized, the declaration is interpreted as a specialization of #2 and not #1.

> All this makes me realize I don't really understand what happens when the compiler sees a call that requires a template instantiation. Does it scan through templates until it finds one that works, then stop? Or does it instantiate all valid options (and then something discards the unneeded ones from the object file)?

The rough sequence for most uses of the name of an overloaded function template is:

1. Do name lookup to determine the list of function templates and functions to be considered.
2. For each function template in the list, attempt template argument deduction.  If template argument deduction fails, or if substituting any template argument into the function type fails, ignore that template from here on.  If successful, this results in a template argument for each template parameter, and one specific function type for the specialization.
3. Do overload resolution in mostly the same way as for non-templates, on the set of non-template functions initially looked up combined with the set of function template specializations determined above.  But if two candidate functions cannot be ordered to say one is a better overload than the other just based on the parameter types and implicit conversions involved, then a non-template function beats a function template specialization, and a specialization from a more specialized function template beats a specialization from a less specialized function template.

Note that during this process, the function types but not the definitions of the function template specializations are instantiated.

Comment: I've had the "more specialized" rule appear to fail (picking arg `int*` over `const int*` when the caller is using `const int*` for example ) if picking the less specialized template allows it to reduce `T` to a `type` rather than a `type pointer`.  Have I hallucinated this?  (It's possible)

Comment: @zzxyz Hard to say without seeing an example. I'm not even sure what you mean by "reduce `T` to a type".

Comment: to reword, I think it’ll prefer a T with less indirection (prefer int vs int*) before preferring a more specialized param. I dunno if that makes any more sense. Honestly the only examples are ridiculously contrived and I guess I don’t care that much :)

Answer (score 4):

Template argument deduction is performed to figure out what function template specialization is named by `template void foo(int**);`; it selects the `T**` one after considering partial ordering. See [[temp.deduct.decl]](https://wg21.link/temp.deduct.decl) and sections linked therein. That's roughly the same process used to pick the function template to call during overload resolution (with some minor differences).

There's no mechanism for instantiating everything that matches. If the compiler can't select a unique function template specialization, the program is simply ill-formed.

> On the other hand, if I put a `static_assert(false)` into the unused one, the compilation fails. Does that mean that it is instantiated?

That's just [[temp.res]/8](https://wg21.link/temp.res#8) at work, as usual. Code that is ill-formed in a way that doesn't depend on a template parameter may be diagnosed immediately without instantiation.